# How to do tolerance analysis in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65008505/4999991), I'm wondering if it is possible to do a one-dimensional [tolerance analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tolerance_analysis) in Excel/VBA. Consider the line bellow with some points on it:

[image]

of course, you need at least `N - 1` independent relative dimensions in order to have a fully defined geometry. And the dimensions are toleranced. It means they are of the `<nominal> ±<tolerance>` nature. If `A = a ±b` and `B = c ±d`, then `A + B = (a + c) ±(b + d)` and `A - B = (a - c) ±(b + d)`. What I want is a table like the one below:

[image]

basically defining `N - 1` values and then get the rest of them. In the above example if the dimensions `①, ②, ③, ④` are given, the dimensions `⑤, ⑥, ⑦, ⑧, ⑨, ⑩` should be calculatable.

The main issue is that I don't know how to approach this problem, to begin with. I assume I need to

1. define a new toleranced dimension data type as I attempted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65008505/4999991).
2. define add and deduct methods for the above data type plus their string representation in the Excel cell
3. I can create and fill the table manually if the above two problems are solved.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the solution requires VBA (or Power Query) and its complexity is way beyond the possibilities of this site.

Comment: Dear @MátéJuhász , I really appreciate your kindness to explain your closing vote. I wish all SO/SE users would have this decency. However, this is unfair because my SO question has already been closed. It is getting more and more frustrating every day to get any help on SO/SE with all the downvotes and closing votes ...

Comment: both sites can help you specific, but sized questions. Format of the sites doesn't fit well for getting help on more complex projects with sometimes vague description. You can get better answers by providing real examples with desired output as we can work on examples providing you the output.

Answer (score 1):

**To answer your first question regarding a data class**

You can use complex math to express the tolerance (min and max, not standard deviation) as part of the imaginary component:

```
A1 =COMPLEX(a, b)
A2 =COMPLEX(c, d)
```

To add is simple:

```
A3 =IMSUM(A1, A2) = (a + c) + i (b+d)
```

But to subtract requires you to conjugate the subtrahend:

```
A4 =IMSUB(A1, IMCONJUGATE(A2)) = (a - c) + i (b+d)
```

For display purposes only:

```
A5 =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A3, "+","+-"),"i","")
```

This will work for symmetric tolerances and whilst only adding and subtracting.

**Now for solving your matrix of unknown dimensions:**

I have worked out a way to determine all the dimensions but not yet while dragging along the tolerances. In brief, if your table looks like this:

[image]

where vi presents the vector from the origin to point i, then dimensions can be presented like this vi - vj = distance from j to i. A positive distance implies i > j and vice versa. The table is meant to be read as v_column - v_row i.e. the cell in column v2 and row v4 is the distance v2 - v4 (and should be a negative value in this example).

The trick is to realise that for any unknown cell in the table, there could be up to n ways to solve it i.e. v3 - v2 = (*v3 - v1*) + (**v1 - v2**) = (*v3 - v2*) + (**v2 - v2**) = (*v3 - v3*) + (**v3 - v2**) = (*v3 - v4*) + (**v4 - v2**) = (*v3 - v5*) + (**v5 - v2**).

If you have a closer look at the italic and bold vectors you'll see the italic ones are all v3 - vj (the V3 column array) and the bold ones vi - v2 (the V2 row array), so that

```
TRANSPOSE(*V3 column*) + (**V2 row**) = { v3 - v2 , v3 - v2 , v3 - v2 ...}
```

I.e. to solve position i,j in the table, add element by element the column i (transposed) and the row j and you'll get a row array with all the elements the same value you are looking to solve vi - vj. However, if there are any "blanks"/additional unknowns, elements of this array will be either blank, NaN error etc and you have to filter it with N() and ISVALUE(), e.g.:

```
=IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT((N(TRANSPOSE(V$2:V$6)) + TRANSPOSE(N(TRANSPOSE($V2:$Z2))))*(TRANSPOSE(ISNUMBER(V$2:V$6)) * ISNUMBER($V2:$Z2)))/SUMPRODUCT((TRANSPOSE(ISNUMBER(V$2:V$6)) * ISNUMBER($V2:$Z2))),"")
```

This approach adds the row and column arrays together using the N() function to convert blanks to zero. Then the array is multiplied by an ISNUMBER mask e.g. { 1, 0 ...} to discard the "other term" of the blank pair. Finally the array is summed to obtain m * (vi - vj), then divided by m (the number of valid (vi - vj) pairs). This formula must be entered as an array formula with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER, then copied and pasted in an n x n table to produce the solved table. If there is any blanks in this table, run the same algorithm a few times and it will progressively fill in the blanks.

Now, this solution is not yet ideal as the tolerances aren't being calculated (yet) - but its food for thought.

Comment: emulating the toleranced dimensions as complex numbers is interesting though. however, it doesn't work in the case of deduction. please check my latest edit. `A - B = (a - c) ±(b + d)`

Comment: My apologies for the bad formatting (corrected now). You must have missed the trick required for deduction. Deduction will work as long as you use the complex conjugate of the subtrahend i.e. A - B* = (a- c) +i (b + d)

Comment: @Foad By the way I am still thinking of a way to do the optimisation in Excel. See this related solution I posted for another optimisation problem: https://superuser.com/questions/1604051/excel-formula-for-optimizing-a-route-where-each-row-represents-a-different-stat/1604194#1604194

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do appreciate your kind support.

Comment: Hi how far along have you gotten with your problem? Were you able to use the complex math idea?

Comment: Hi, not far really. it was the weekend. But I'm doing [some investigations](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/k2isgi/documentation_examples_tutorials_for_excel_com/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3). I might be able to use COM objects. Plus my assumption for tolerance arithmetic was wrong. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3923985/tolerance-dimensions-arithmetic-or-how-to-add-or-subtract-values-with-probabilit). Not sure if complex numbers can help.

Comment: I don't think you were wrong. Tolerances as far as I know, indicate absolute max and min values and would add and subtract exactly like to said. It is not specified as a "standard deviation" (which would mean 99.7% of data falls with 3x the std deviation - give a normal distribution). I.e. 5  ± 1 means min 4 and max.6. 5 with σ = 1 implies the mean dimension is 5 and most the data would sit between 2 and 8 given a normal distribution. *IF* you need to work with std devs it would may sense that they add up quadratically as they are defined as such.

Comment: @Foad solution updated...