# Writing an Excel Spreadsheet Formula

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I need an Excel formula that will find the most efficient combination of products based on the value of a single cell.

e.g., I have a product list as follows: 400 / 220 / 150 / 110 / 72 / 60.
I need a formula that will apply items from the list based on a value of another "cell".

The combined items taken from the list need to add up to the closest but greater number above the value of the "cell" using the least number of items from the list.

So if the value of the "cell" is 660. the formula needs to know that instead of 6 x 110 the formula needs to know the correct response is:  1 x 400 (+) 1 x 220 (+) 1 x 60  = 680

How do I write the formula?

Comment: You'll need to better define what you mean by most efficient. In other words, why is 680 more efficient than 660 (6 X 100). or than 800 (2 X 400), or even 660 (3 X 220). Also which one do you pick if two solutions equally efficient? Answering these questions should lead you to your solution...

Comment: Oh and the answer will probably be over a series of cells. I'll say a one cell answer (if that is even possible) will look substantially different from what you probably envision.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, you need to calculate the process from the result, but the Excel formula is the process to get the result.

Comment: This is a tricky sum to compute as there are multiple solutions. I believe the "best" answer for your example problem will actually be 1x400+1x150+1x110=660. And as @gns100 mentioned, what metric do you use to decide which criteria is more important? (distance away from 660 vs number of items). If the fewest number of items is always the primary concern, just choose the biggest item "a" in your list so that (QUOTIENT(x,a)+1) * a > x where x is your target, e.g. a = 400, x = 660, n = QUOTIENT(x,a)+1 = QUOTIENT(660,400)+1 = 1+1 = 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would help if you would qualify your requirements in formulae e.g.

Say you have sorted items a,b,c,d,e,f with a > b > c > d > e > f

Then with a target cell x, you need to find m,n,o,p,q,r (all positive integers) so that

m*a + n*b + o*c + p*d + q*e + r*f >= x

and

```
y = m+n+o+p+q+r, where y < y(mi,ni,oi,pi,qi,ri)  for all combinations of mi,ni,oi,pi,qi,ri
```

and perhaps with another criteria like

m*a + n*b + o*c + p*d + q*e + r*f <= 1.1 * x

In some ways this is similar to the route optimisation problem I answered here ([Excel Formula for optimizing a route where each row represents a different "station" that can do different things](https://superuser.com/questions/1604051/excel-formula-for-optimizing-a-route-where-each-row-represents-a-different-stat)) but with the added complexity that you can visit a route more than once, which means the bit math trick no longer applies. To brute force this, you would need to generate the answer for all possible combinations, where the max of any single m, n... or r is QUOTIENT(x, m or n or...r)+1. For your example the solution space would span m,n,o,p,q,r = {0..2, 0..4, 0..5, 0..7, 0..10, 0..12}. You can generate such a table in excel using variations of MOD(QUOTIENT(ROW()-2,(n+1)*(o+1)*...(r+1)),m+1). Then calculate the total for each row/combination and compare that to the target value. In an adjacent column calculate the number of items y and multi-sort first by the total and then by the number of items.